# App Invites for Android: Message failed to send with missing container client ID

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate new Google Play Services api "[App Invites for Android](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app)". I followed all the steps as per guide and generated the `gogole-services.json` file. But when I send an invite to a selected friend via SMS or Email, I get the same error everytime.

```
Message failed to send
```

on ADB log getting this:

```
E/AppInviteAgent﹕ generic::13: generic::INTERNAL: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request must associate a valid container client application ID.
```

Now it seems my app is missing some sort of client app ID but not getting any clue how to configure it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because you used the SHA1 fingerprint from your release key. But the build you test is signed with the android debug key.

Comment: Thanks that was the case. I thought I did try with the prod key as I set the prod signing in the debug build for Inapp purchase testing but that was reset somehow.

Comment: I have this problem too. I sign thev new  app with my SH1 fingerprint but the problem do not solved!:(

Comment: @HamidrezaHosseinkhani Have you solved your problem yet?

Comment: Thanks, it works, I had the same problem for a release version of my app. Getting the sha1 of the release signing key and adding it to the FireBase console resolved the problem, from the Android Studio terminal type:
keytool -exportcert -list -v \-alias KEY_ALIAS -keystore PATH_TO_YOUR_SIGNING_KEY